# Oracle SQL. Is there any way to constrain a type?

Tags: sql, oracle

(I'm learning Oracle SQL)

I want to declare a type, constraining his possible values to only some choices. What is the best practice for this?

I had been searching a lot of things and found nothing. This is a basic function on any kind of code, so it should already be a solved problem. Maybe there is a common pattern to solve it.

It looks like Oracle SQL does not allow constrains on types (neither it has domains)

I do not want to duplicate the constrain code on each table which uses the type, because that would duplicate the code one time for each table, and that's bad coding practice on any language.

Please, add an example.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: @Michael McGriff I want to avoid repeating constrain-code for the same kind of type of data. On most programming languages, I avoid repetition by defining a type, and using that type everywhere. Oracle SQL does not supports defining a type with associated code.

Comment: Only thing I can find about that is using references to an object table, [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/server.901/a88856/c14ordb.htm), under Scoped Refs, basically what [MarkD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44332604/2847379) is suggesting, but at the type level.

Comment: @Michael McGriff I had been reading the link and other documentation for Scoped Refs, and still I do not understand if a scoped ref limits the pointer to existing elements on the pointed table, or if a new pointer creates a new row in the pointed table (with that table constraints for his rows). In other words, I do not understand if the pointed table works as an enumeration of licit values or as storage of instances with unlimited number of rows.

Comment: My impression is that if it a certain value wasn't listed on the object table, it wouldn't be allowed anywhere that the object table was being referenced.  Basically exactly like a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at restricting the values that can go into a field on some tables you could create a reference table for those values. Then your tables that can contain the values can have a foreign key to the reference restricting them to only values in the reference table.

example:

Table ground type:

```
+---+--------+
|ID |Type    |
+---+--------+
|1  |Grass   |
|2  |Tarmac  |
|3  |Concrete|
```

Table Tennis Courts

```
+--------+------+----------+
|CourtID |Adress|GroundType|
+--------+------+----------+
| 1      |locat | 2        |
| 2      |locat | 3        |
| 3      |locat | 1        |
```

Table Basketball court

```
+--------+------+----------+
|CourtID |Adress|GroundType|
+--------+------+----------+
| 1      |locat | 3        |
| 2      |locat | 2        |
| 3      |locat | 2        |
```

Comment: You mean that all data elements of the same type should be stored into a single table? I'm a beginner. I'm worried for example, when the code deletes the pointer to "Table Basketball court", what happens to the pointed item inside "Table Basketball court"? It is left as a memory leak? It should be manually deleted?

Comment: I do not understand, when new rows are added to another table,  if new rows (pointers) on another table are limited to the ones on "Table Basketball court", or a new row is created, and stored inside "Table Basketball court". On the first case, it would work 'as an enumeration', and in the second case 'as a type definition'. Or maybe it can work both ways?